# Problem reading XML with AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

How can i call a specific image tag based on the size parameter of my XML in AS3? I know that
track.image will return all the image tags but i am unsure of how to target a specific image tag based on the size tag. My XML is as follows. Cheers in advance for any help.

```
<track>
  <name>Hello</name>
  <image size="small"></image>
  <image size="medium"></image>
  <image size="large"></image>
</track>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will test for a specific attribute:

```
var myImagePath:String = yourXML.image.(@size == "small");
```

Where yourXML is the xml object...

If your xml tree is more complicated, just dot your way down from the root. Also - the root node is implied by flash, so you can leave it out.